# How can we make use of common methods (like log-in method) shared across all the files in unit/test class file?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am new to selenium webdriver. I have seven different unit tests and different testmethods in each unit test and I am using same website and log in details in each unit test. Is there any way to create only one file or Testfixturesetup or anything? And use that file's reference in each unit test so I can change log in details at one place which affects in all Testmethods.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("example.com);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();


IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
email.SendKeys("abc@xyz.com");

IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
password.SendKeys("abcdef");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]"));
login.Submit();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Is there any way to create theses lines of code in one file? And use its reference in unit test. So every time I try to run testmethod it first go to the portal and log in so its easy to maintain the code. In case I want to change the log in details so I can change at one place. Please experts need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please list some ways that you have tried, or researched. Or any print outs that can further help us in answering your question.

Comment: I got 7 unit tests and 2-3 test methods in each unit test. Now every time I try to run the test I have to go to the url, enter email address and password and log in. I tried to minimize the code for each unit test by creating method and calling that method in [TestMethods]. So I have to create 7 methods for 7 unit tests. I want to create only one method and I can use that in every unit test just by calling it. Is there any way? I tried to search on google but couldn't find any solution. Is there any solution available? I am new to the testing so don't have much experience. Thanks.

Comment: are you using Nunit ?

Comment: I am using .net platform. In that I have created different test units. But As I was looking on google. I found something regarding TestfixtureSetup and TestFixtureTearDown and to use this I have to use namespace using NUnit.Framework. I don't know exactly how it works as I am new to testing platform. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you have posted is no where related to Selenium. It is basically you need to run couple of statements (shown above) as part of each test which are there in more that one test class file.

As you suggested 'TestfixtureSetup' and 'TestFixtureTearDown' can be used for Unit tests and can not be used for test methods. For test method you need to use TestInitialize and TestCleanUp for achieving it.

I would suggest to create base class, which contains the common methods (like login) and inherit that class to required unit test class / test class file. And call the related method in the Initializing part.

```
public class TestBase
{
    IWebDriver driver;

    public TestBase()
    {
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("example.com);
       driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    public void Login()
    {       
       IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
       email.SendKeys("abc@xyz.com");

       IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
       password.SendKeys("abcdef");
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

       IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'LogIn')]"));
       login.Submit();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class LoginTests : TestBase
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInit()
    {
        Login();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void MyTestCleanUp()
    {
        LogOut(); // Implement log out functionality.
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginTestOne()
    {    
       // test method logic here.
    }
}
```

(Pseudo code - not complied)

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for. Its working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different unit test frameworks to selenium tests -

1. Nunit
2. CSunit
3. Visual Studio Test Framework
4. Mbunit

All these frameworks supports some form of [setup] and [teardown] attributes so that you can apply various settings and create global objects that can be used across multiple tests .

If you are using VS integrated unit testing framework, here are the methods -

1. [ClassInitialize], [ClassCleanup] - called for each Class Under Test
2. [TestInitialize], [TestCleanup] - called for each Method Under Test
3. [AssemblyInitialize], [AssemblyCleanup] - called for each Assembly Under Test

More details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx

Nunit has also similar stuff e.g.  [SetUp], [TeaDown], [TestFixtureSetUp], [TestFixtureTearDown] .
More Details - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4